# networking machines connected in series

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 3 machines that are connected in series.  Machine #1 is running roscore and is networked locally to Machine #2.  Everything works fine between those two.  Machine #3 accesses Machine #2 via a VPN connection, but is not allowed to access Machine #1 directly.  How do I get Machine #3 to see the rosmaster on Machine #1?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262280/networking-machines-connected-in-series/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a routing problem.

Get machine 2 to route the network that machine 1 is on to/from the VPN connection.

Alternatively: get your VPN server to give incoming connections IPs in the range of the network between machine 1 and 2.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0